# Try To Understand ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I try to build an application that can convert a PDF to an excel with C#. 
I have searched for some library to help me with this, but most of them are commercially licensed, so I ended up to iTextSharp.dll

It's good that is free, but I rarely find any good open source documentation for it.
These are some link that I have read:

1. https://yoda.entelect.co.za/view/9902/extracting-data-from-pdf-files
2. https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp
3. http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/ASPDotNet/Read-PDF-and-Convert-to-Stream.aspx?id=34

there're more. But, most of them did not really explain what use of the code.
So this is most common code in IText with C#:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(); // my new file that will have pdf content?
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(myPath); // This maybe how IText read the pdf?
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++) // looping for read all content in pdf?
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(); // ?
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy); // ?
            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(currentText))); // maybe how IText convert the data to text?
            text.Append(currentText); // maybe the full content?
        }
        pdfReader.Close(); // to close the PdfReader?
```

As you can see, I still do not have a clear knowledge of the IText code that I have. Tell me, if my knowledge is correct and give me an answer for code that I still not understand.

Thank You.

Comment: There are a lot of examples on google. one of them: https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/using-c-and-itextsharp-to-create-a-pdf/

Comment: So... you want to use iText, but (1.) you want to start with an old version that is no longer supported (namely iText 5 instead of iText 7), (2.) instead of going to [the official jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version), you read obsolete third-party tutorials, and (3.) iText is AGPL software, that means that you can use if for free if you obey the rules of the AGPL. Are you sure you are aware of those rules?

Comment: Also: you say you want to convert a PDF file to an Excel file, but you don't ask yourself if this is even possible (in general). Is your PDF a Tagged PDF? If so, are there table tags inside? If not, how do you think the PDF will know what are columns and what are rows? Without tags inside the PDF, you may see a table with your human eyes, but a machine just sees text and lines, no table. The only valid answer to your question "Try To Understand ITextSharp" is "Try to understand PDF first!" You are trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: By the way, concerning the line you commented *// maybe how IText convert the data to text?* - Nope, that line is a complicated way to do nothing which in particular in third-party tutorials and also in some answers here on stack overflow can be found. Whenever one asks the respective author to explain let alone provide an example for which that line is necessary, there usually is no explanation and consistently is no proof in the few cases with explanation.

Comment: I see, this is my mistake. I did not read well what is itext library. I've tried www.sautinsoft.com and it's very easy to use for convert, and that really make me lost. So, I have read again about itext and the program work. It read all data in pdf (only page 1). And what I need now is to write it to excel. Thx All, I'll make new question soon and feel free to answer it again :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by explaining a bit about PDF.
PDF is not a 'what you see is what you get'-format.

Internally, PDF is more like a file containing instructions for rendering software. Unless you are working with a tagged PDF file, a PDF document does not naturally have a concept of 'paragraph' or 'table'.

If you open a PDF in notepad for instance, you might see something like

```
7 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica-Oblique/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>
endobj
```

Instructions in the document get gathered into 'objects' and objects are numbered, and can be cross-referenced.

As Bruno already indicated in the comments, this means that finding out what a table is, or what the content of a table is, can be really hard.

The PDF document itself can only tell you things like:

- object 8 is a line from [50, 100] to [150, 100]
- object 125 is a piece of text, in font Helvetica, at position [50, 110]

With the iText core library you can

- get all of these objects (which iText calls PathRenderInfo, TextRenderInfo and ImageRenderInfo objects)
- get the graphics state when the object was rendered (which font, font-size, color, etc)

This can allow you to write your own parsing logic.
For instance:

- gather all the PathRenderInfo objects
- remove everything that is not a perfect horizontal or vertical line
- make clusters of everything that intersects at 90 degree angles
- if a cluster contains more than a given threshold of lines, consider it a table

Luckily, the `pdf2Data` solution (an iText add-on) already does that kind of thing for you.

For more information go to http://pdf2data.online/